# SQL syntax error in UPDATE

Tags: php, sql

This code will receive id and area from another php code and I'm sure that it received them correctly. This code purpose is to update the area where id is equal to the id that the user entered. I run the code, I got SQL syntax error from the this statement.

```
$sql = "UPDATE complain SET area = ".$area."WHERE num = ".$id."";
```

Anyone have any idea what's wrong?

```
<?php

$area = $_GET['area']; 
$id = $_GET['id']; 

echo $area;
echo $id;

//$Area = $_POST['variable'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sfa";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 $sql = "UPDATE complain SET area = ".$area."WHERE num = ".$id."";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing `$area` is a string, not an integer. Then it should be wrapped in singlequotes. Your real issue is there's no space before the `WHERE` keyword. Make it `...SET area = '".$area."' WHERE...`

Comment: Also, you should be using prepared statements, you're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Before Where Clause add some space, making your query like

```
UPDATE complain SET area = ".$area." WHERE num = ".$id."
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing space between `".$area."WHERE`

the result is then

```
UPDATE complain SET area = 2WHERE num = 0815
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this query. It is working fine and updating the records -

"UPDATE complain SET area = '.$area.' WHERE num = '.$id.'"

Answer (score 0):

Following query should work:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE complain"."SET area = $area".
        "WHERE num = $id";
```

Hope it helps!